# Convert a primarykey column from int to bigint has the column is approaching 2 billion rows in shortest time

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion, large-data

I am having a table with 1.87 billion rows as its approaching the limit we are looking to convert to bigint.
we are trying to add a new column with bigint datatype and remove the primary key constraints copy the data in batching manner and later remove the original column and rename the new column. but its taking long time  4 to 5 hours in test environment with 60 million rows.

Table Definition

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableRecordsHistory](
[PrimaryKeyColumnID] [int] NOT NULL,
[RecordType] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[DisplayOrder] [int] NOT NULL,
[DisplayText] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Hours] [decimal](8, 2) NULL,
[Amount] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
[Created] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TableRecordsHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Created] ASC,
[PrimaryKeyColumnID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  =          ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON)
    )

    GO

   SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
   GO

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableRecordsHistory]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT          [FK_TableRecordsHistory_TableRecords] FOREIGN KEY([Created], [PrimaryKeyColumnID])
  REFERENCES [dbo].[TableRecords] ([Created], [PrimaryKeyColumnID])
  GO

  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableRecordsHistory] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_TableRecordsHistory_TableRecords]
  GO
```

I am afraid how long will it take in production,

its not working correctly

```
SET @NumProcessedRows = 0
SET @BatchNum = 0

WHILE @NumProcessedRows < @RowCount
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION tx
    BEGIN TRY

        SET @BatchNum = @BatchNum + 1

                SET @BatchID = @@IDENTITY

        IF (@NumProcessedRows + @BatchSize) < @RowCount
            SET @UpperLimitRow = @NumProcessedRows + @BatchSize
        ELSE
            SET @UpperLimitRow = @RowCount

        update TableName
        set NewColumn = OldColumn
        WHERE OldColumn BETWEEN @NumProcessedRows AND @UpperLimitRow    


                IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            COMMIT TRANSACTION tx
        END
```

Comment: What size batches are you using? What's the full table definition?

Comment: So that's 60 batches with 4-5 minutes each on average. That does seem pretty slow. Is the dev environment on really bad hardware? What wait types are you seeing when it runs?

Comment: Oh I've just noticed your index is a composite one and not useful for this. You would need to partition the workload up so you can seek into each batch.

Comment: Can you batch by created instead of `id`? So you process date ranges of approx the desired size?

Comment: this table is already a partition table by month, i will try to batch by created instead of id

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new table with the column to be changed as bigint. Write all data from existing table into the new table. Then, rename the tables so that they are swapped.

If you do not have time to rename the tables, you could create a synonym pointing to your current table, create a new table like described above and then just change the synonym.

Comment: Copying the entire table will it not take longer time.

Comment: @user3494425 not necessarily. You might benefit from minimal logging and fewer page splits.

Comment: @MartinSmith ok will work on creating a new table and compare the time differances between two approaches,. any approach which helps moving data from one table to other fastly.

Answer (score 0):

> It's taking long time 4 to 5 hours in test environment with 60 million
>   rows.

You say in the comments that you are splitting this up into 60 batches of 1 million rows.

Your index on `Created,PrimaryKeyColumnID` does *not* permit a seek on `PrimaryKeyColumnID` so your query needs to perform 60 full table scans when identifying the rows to update.

This adds up to **3.6 billion** rows scanned.

If you were to attempt this strategy on the live database with 1.87 billion rows and the same batch size you would end up with 1870 full scans on a 1.87 billion rows = 3.5 trillion rows.

I suggest that you either add a useful index that allows a range seek or simply alter the query to something like

```
WHERE Created >= @StartDateTime AND Created < @EndDateTime
```

And increment those datetime variables by some value that will end up having the roughly desired batch size.